# Python - can you use re.compile looking for two strings?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python 2.7 and have a this in my code: `regexp = re.compile('ttp_ws_sm_(\d)_')`

That searches in my loop for different characters as in my sample (after the third underscore). I need to also do the same for strings like `'ttpv1_(\d+)_'`

The two things I have tried are:

```
regexp = re.compile('ttp_ws_sm_(\d)_' or 'ttpv1_(\d+)_')
```

and

```
name = ('ttp_ws_sm_(\d+)_' or 'ttpv1_(\d+)_')
regexp = re.compile(name)
```

Here's some example data:

```
sample filheader row
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,117
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,31
date,ttp_ws_sm_045_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,145
date,ttp_ws_sm_045_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,55
date,ttp_ws_sm_057_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,98
date,ttpv1_001_, , , , , , , , , , , ,67
date,ttpv1_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,67*e is
```

complete code is:

```
from collections import defaultdict

import sys
import csv
import re
import os

#variables
output_path = '\\\\Isfs\\data$\\GIS Carto\TTP_Draw_Count'
source = '\\\\Isfs\\data$\\GIS Carto\TTP_Draw_Count'
name = ('ttp_ws_sm_(\d+)_' or 'ttpv1_(\d+)_')

def main():
    result = defaultdict(int)
    regexp = re.compile(name)

    with open(os.path.join(source, 'TTP_13_08.csv'), 'r') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)

        for row in rows:
            match = regexp.search(row[1])
            if match:
                result[match.group(1)] += int(row[13])

    for key, value in result.items():

         print ("Club %s %s" % (key, value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I don't use name and just put either of both strings in the compile statement I only return one set of totals. I need to have both sets combine and print for "001", '045'

Comment: Please format your sample data so that it is readable and clarify the question to explicitly identify your desired result.

Comment: And a minor point: you're not correctly escaping backslashes in `output_path` and `source`. You got lucky because `\T` is not a valid escape sequence.

Comment: Actually I meant to take the output path out. That is something else I will tackle later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a regex that matches either `'ttp_ws_sm_(\d+)_'` or `'ttpv1_(\d+)_'`?

You can use the [pipe character `|`](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters):

```
re.compile(r'(?:ttp_ws_sm|ttpv1)_(\d+)_')
```

`?:` makes the first group [non-capturing](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups).

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?:ttp_ws_sm|ttpv1)_(\d+)_')
>>> pattern.match('ttpv1_001_').group(1)
'001'
>>> pattern.match('ttp_ws_sm_045_blank').group(1)
'045'
```

---

`'ttp_ws_sm_(\d+)_' or 'ttpv1_(\d+)_'` doesn't work because it is actually the same as `'ttp_ws_sm_(\d+)_'`.  See Max's answer for an explanation.

Comment: I tried it and didn't get my desired total. Seems it is only going through the first string (ttp_ws_sm_(\d+) and not total the rows with ttpv1.

Comment: I guess that's because the digits in `ttpv1_(\d+)_` are `.group(2)` now (which is clearly not what you want). I'll update my answer.

Comment: This question can be closed. Using regexp = re.compile(r'(?:ttp_ws_sm|ttpv1)_(\d+)_')   worked perfectly.

Comment: @MikeHirschmann A better regex pattern is ``ttp(?:_ws_sm|v1)_(\d+)_``

Answer (score 4):

You should read a Python book. You have some severe misunderstandings of the language.

```
'ttp_ws_sm(\d+)_' or 'ttpv1_(\d+)_'
```

is a Boolean expression. Python interprets nonempty strings as truthy so it interprets this as (true thing or true thing). When the first part of a Boolean or is true, Python doesn't even look at the second part and just returns the first. Look:

```
('foo' or 'bar') == 'foo'
>>> True
```

That's why it (accidentally) works inside `re.compile`. Passing a Boolean expression to `re.compile` doesn't really make sense.

Secondly it's not clear what you're even trying to accomplish here. A single regexp might not be appropriate or could require different capture groups.

Comment: I am searching for answers in two books - Learning Python and Python Phrasebook. I am also doing a couple of online tutorials. I am learning python on the fly and it just hasn't sunk in since this is my first coding attempt. The code works fine if I just look for the string. Just trying to look for both.

Comment: I should re-emphasize: read **a** Python book. Grabbing pieces from a bunch of different sources to solve your immediate problem when you've never coded before is going to give you a patchy, confusing understanding of the language.

Answer (score 1):

### Read the doc:

> '|'
> A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular
> expression that will match either A or B.
> http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

### Read the doc:

> csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
> (...)
> If csvfile is
> a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where
> that makes a difference.
> http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> line = 'date,ttp_ws_sm_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,117 date,ttp_ws_sm_001_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,31 date,ttp_ws_sm_045_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,145 date,ttp_ws_sm_045_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,55 date,ttp_ws_sm_057_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,98 date,ttpv1_001_, , , , , , , , , , , ,67 date,ttpv1_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,67*e'
>>> name = re.compile(r'(?:ttp_ws_sm\d+_)|(?:ttpv1_\d+_)')
>>> name.findall()
>>> ['ttp_ws_sm_001', 'ttp_ws_sm_045', 'ttp_ws_sm_045', 'ttp_ws_sm_057', 'ttpv1_001_', 'ttpv1_001_']
```

Comment: `There's probably some "grouping" syntax that doesn't have the side-effect of making it a "group" in the return from findall.` - Yes there is, it's `(?:blabla)` :)